# What If There Is A Memory Leak In Virtual Environment?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

What I understood from reading some web articles is that just like any other program, the host OS allocates X amount of memory to virtual OS and when I start any program on virtual OS, the virtual OS fetches the exact amount of memory needed for the program.

When I shut the virtual OS down, it returns the allocated memory to the host OS.

But what happens if there is a memory leakage in the virtual OS environment? I am starting to learn C, and my professor says that in dynamic memory allocation operations, permanent leakage can happen in the host OS.

But what if it happens in virtual environment? I guess the program will give back ALL of the memory allocated to the host OS when I shut it down, right? What happens when I start the virtual host again the next time? Does the memory leakage show up there permanently?

Just getting afraid before I even start writing my first program in C.

P. S. If I use websites like Repl.it and use memory allocation over there, will it cause damage to my system still?

Comment: Once the process consuming the memory is killed, all the memory is released. Nothing is permanently consumed.

Comment: Any modern OS will reclaim all memory from a process after its exit, so memory leaks are only a problem during the execution of the process.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. So, I am correct in thinking that as I shut down the virtual os, it returns all the memory back and also when I restart it later on, it does not have any blocked memory from previous session, right?

Comment: @SamC basically yes.

Comment: Trying to see the worst case, or a way how you could get what you fear: If your virtual OS (and maybe also the VM engine) supports persistence (including running processes and their memory) it might have the same memory issue after restoring the situation before it was shut down. I.e. a "shut down" with the meaning "hobernate". Otherwise I agree with the other comments.

Comment: @Yunnosch Might be a silly question but does Virtualbox support persistence?

Comment: Not a silly question, but something of a silly answer: I do not know. (And I missed a specification of environment.) Just thinking generally of the edge cases (maybe leaving OPs exact usecase, I admit). I meant "VM engine" as a generic term, hope I did not hit a specific prodcut name. (And I meant "hibernate" by the way ;-) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory leak can occur when you allocate some memory (with `malloc` in C) and you never free that memory, this can happen for a number of reasons.

Now the important thing to understand is that this **allocated memory will be released once the process is finished running**.

When you setup your VM you set the maximum amount of memory it can consume. When you shut down your VM it will also be released.

You can't cause a "permanent" memory leakage if the program you write doesn't run. If the OS has some always running service with memory leak than it will slow down when it is out of memory but when you restart, all the memory will be released again.

So don't let this stop you, you can't damage your computer and you can always recover it by exiting the program. (or restarting the PC in a worst case scenario
)

EDIT:

As it was mentioned in the comments there is a special scenario when you leak shared memory, in this case exiting the program might not release the memory but I consider this the worst case scenario and a reboot will solve this problem as well. (still not permanent)

Comment: Notice however that you *can* have "persistent" (=until next reboot) leaks if you leak shared memory.

Comment: That's true, all add it to the answer however the OP's question indicated a permanent damage which can't be fixed, and allocating a shared memory (without freeing it) is certainly nastier but it will still be solved with a reboot as you mentioned, so I considered these cases the worst case scenario.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is meant to provide a different view point, in addition to the good answer(s) and comments, which I agree with.

I am trying to see the worst case, i.e a way how you could get what you fear.
You probably have an environment which does not match the following assumptions, in that case my construct does of course not apply.

- your virtual OS supports "persistence"
  (i.e. you can shut it down in a "hibernate" way, it can start with the same running processes and their restored memory content)
- your virtualisation engine also supports persistence of the virtual OS
- shutting down for persistence in virtual OS is possible with a process occupying a critical amount of memory (sanity checks could prevent this)
- virtualisation engine also does not mind the depleted memory and allows persistence
- you choose to use persistent shutdown,
  rebooting the virtual OS normally would include killing the evil process and reclaiming the memory  (this is discussed by other answers and comments, but thanks to MrBlaise for proposing the clarification here)

In this circumstance I imagine that you can have:

- a process which has taken (and ran out of) all avaiable memory
- but has not crashed or otherwise triggered emergency measures
- then this situation is saved for persistence before shutting down, successfully
- then you restart the virtual OS
- it restores the previous situation, i.e. returns from hiberantion
- the restored previous situation contains a still/again running process which has taken all memory

I think this will still only affect the virtual OS, not the host.

Please note that I intentionally made all necessary assumptions just to get the situation you are afraid of. Some of the assumptions are quite "daring".
I imagine for example that anything supporting persistence should have sanity checks, which at least detect the memory issue and ask how to handle.

*(By the way, I do not know about virtualisation engines which support persistence, neither whether any do not support it. I am thinking in the generic, theoretical area.

In case I have invented the persistence for virtualisation engines (can't believe it), I claim this as prior art. ;-))*

Comment: If you run out of memory the OS will start to use your drive as memory (HDD, SSD) which is significantly slower, in this stage if you start a new process you will definitely see a major slowdown (but no damage at all), and this can still be fixed by rebooting the virtual machine, or if such thing occurs on the host rebooting the host. My point is whatever you do nothing is permanent and nothing will damage your computer (in terms of memory leakage).

Comment: @MrBlaise so, even against persistence? Like if it is set successfully as Yunnosch said?

Comment: @MrBlaise I agree with what you say, but do not see a conflict with my answer. Either see swap memory as part of available memory (and it is used up within the constraints of the virtual OS) or the slow-down is the undesirable but not emergency triggering effect OP is afraid of and is saved/restored with persistence. (Oh, SamC said something similar, thanks.)

Comment: @SamC What Yunnosch said will only occur inside the VM and it will only consume the maximum amount of memory that you gave it, this issue caused by 'persistence' can easily be fixed with a reboot on the VM, rebooting the VM frees the VM's memory just like rebooting the host frees the memory. Also shutting down the VM will always free the memory, this can only occur if you make your VM go to sleep (hibernate), in this case the memory will be written to the hard drive and the actual memory will be released.

Comment: @MrBlaise Also true, but also no conflict with my answer. This I actually state explicitly in my answer. But I will edit to clarify.

Comment: @Yunnosch I didn't comment because I think what you have written is wrong I just wanted to add my thoughts and clarify some things. :)

Comment: @MrBlaise I know, and I appreciate and am using your feedback. Thanks.

Comment: @MrBlaise Ah got it, thanks.

Comment: @Yunnosch, thanks for bringing the interesting topic up :)